# Oracle Procedure Grant privileges List

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle-sqldeveloper, privileges

I've searched a lot in order to find a table which can list all the privileges that can be granted over a procedure, for instance.

I've tried to get this information around these tables:

- `all_sys_privs`
- `session_privs`
- `user_sys_privs`
- `dba_sys_privs`
- `system_privilege_map`

but without success.

What I want to get is a list that says:

> "Procedures objects can grant EXECUTE and DEBUG privileges on USERS/ROLES".

Could you help me in this one?

Comment: @the swine, thanks for the corrections suggestions.

Could you help me in this one?

Comment: It would seem that you already have an answer :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the table you are looking for is `V$OBJECT_PRIVILEGE`

```
SQL> select * from V$OBJECT_PRIVILEGE where object_type_name = 'PROCEDURE';

OBJECT_TYPE_NAME     OBJECT_TYPE_ID PRIVILEGE_ID PRIVILEGE_NAME
-------------------- -------------- ------------ ---------------
PROCEDURE                         7           12 EXECUTE
PROCEDURE                         7           26 DEBUG
```

Comment: Like a glove! Thank you very much @Haki!
Kind regards!